# MySQL wont take data from table

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL won't take data from a table; why isn't my code working?

I'm trying to check if the password is correct but it wont get the password for some reason. I should also note that this code worked on Windows VPS but now that I'm using Ubuntu 14, it's not working. I've tried chmod 777 but that doesn't help, either. Any ideas as to what can I do?

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
    $username =  mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['user']);
    mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)or error("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or error(mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `ranks`, `active` FROM $table WHERE username='$username'") or die (mysql_error()); 
    list($id,$username,$password,$rank,$active) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    if($_COOKIE['pass'] == $password) {
        $display = "Hello, $username!";
    } else {
        $display = "Invalid Password, attempted post data fail?";
    }
} else {
    $display = "You are not logged in!";
}
```

Comment: **Do not store passwords in plain text**.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And I guess you need the value out of the $_POST array, not cookie.

Comment: clear your apostrophes -> `mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, ranks, active FROM $table WHERE username='$username'")`

Comment: Yikes... @slaks it looks like he's storing the password in a cookie to boot.  Don't do that either!!!  Yikes

Comment: And don't just rely on add_slashes and mysql_escape.  Use parameterized queries (aka bound queries) to properly render queries safe.  Jamming that $username in there is dangerous no matter how you try to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `ranks`, `active` FROM $table WHERE username='{$username}'") or die (mysql_error());
```

If it won't work, show me how you insert things in your user table. Didn't you use `PASSWORD()` function on the `password`?

If you did, try this:

```
$pass = $_COOKIE['pass'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `password`, `ranks`, `active` FROM $table WHERE username='{$username}' and password=PASSWORD('{$pass}')") or die (mysql_error()); 
if($result) {
    list($id,$username,$password,$rank,$active) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $display = "Hello, $username!";
} else {
    $display = "You are not logged in!";
}
```